# Finding Pin on MCU

Tags: microcontroller, avr

I am fairly new to programming MCU. I have an ATtiny2313 and the datasheet came with a layout of how the pins are configured; however, finding pin 1, since the mcu is a square, is tough for me. I share the images of the diagram and the actual unit. Maybe I am overthinking the issue? Further reading materials are also greatly appreciated.

**This is the datasheets diagram**
[image]

**This is the actual unit**
[image]

Comment: there is a dot in the drawing in the corner, flip the chip over and look at the back and you will also see a dot, this is how you figure out where you are.

Comment: Should belong to https://electronics.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.  It's about how to read an electronic component's datasheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the *Packaging information* section at the end of datasheet. There are physical properties of packages described including any marking to identify pin 1.

[image: ATtiny2313 package]

In some situations (some really small ICs) it can be hard to identify right pin 1 marking. In production, one simply rely on orientation of chip in the tape, but for populating boards by hand, little trick can come handy anytime you are not sure, you have identified pin 1 correctly.

In virtually any IC, there are ESD protection diodes from GND to any IO pin and prom IO pin to power rail. So, if you put a multimeter in diode measuring mode, you should see a drop about 700 mV (actual value can vary) when the positive probe is touching a ground pin and the negative probe any data pin, or when the negative probe is touching a positive voltage rail pin and the positive probe any IO pin. It is not 100 % fail-proof way, but really good and useful hint.